# Steam cannot launch properly and crash

Tags: games, xfce, steam

New to ubuntu. I downloaded and used steam for month (about half a year), until two weeks ago. Today I tried to start Steam, but couldn't : the steam process just disappeared after some time. I reinstalled it, new problem : it slowed my computer a lot more than usual and crashed in the login page. I deleted all folders and directory with a command, and reinstalled it entirely: new issue : the process start, then an invisible window appear (I could see it with alt-tab) but nothing else. After 10 to 20 second, the steam process disappear. Sometimes, it crashes the whole computer instead.

Important things to know:

- The first time I lauched steam after the re-installation, a small windows with the steam color no button and no way to resize it appeared. It was called "steam" in alt-tab, but could'nt do anything with it. here is a link an image I hopefully got : https://ibb.co/d6FgQFD
- I switched from the ubuntu desktop (called Unity-gnome I think?) to the xfce desktop (the one from Xubuntu), for performance reason. I still have the same issue when I start steam with the original Ubuntu desktop, but it is the major change that occurred in my computer.
- I am on Ubuntu 20.04
- My computer is a potato computer from Dell computer (model : Latitude 3570) : *Computer hardware (using inxi command in a terminal):
  CPU: Dual Core Intel Core i5-6200U (-MT MCP-)     ;
  speed/min/max: 800/400/2800 MHz Kernel: 5.8.0-38-generic x86_64 Up: 39m ;
  Mem: 2070.5/3766.8 MiB (55.0%) Storage: 465.76 GiB (40.2% used) Procs: 317   ;
  Shell: bash 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38   ;*

Here is the logs from */home/valentin/.steam/steam/logs/bootstrap_log.txt*

```
[2021-02-03 17:00:48] Startup - updater built Dec 20 2020 23:07:02
[2021-02-03 17:00:50] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2021-02-03 17:00:50] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-02-03 17:00:50] 1. http://client-download.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'baked in'
[2021-02-03 17:00:50] 2. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2021-02-03 17:00:50] Checking for update on startup
[2021-02-03 17:00:50] Checking for available updates...
[2021-02-03 17:00:50] Downloading manifest: http://client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2021-02-03 17:00:51] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1608507519, installed version 1608507519, downloaded version 0
[2021-02-03 17:00:51] Nothing to do
[2021-02-03 17:00:51] Verifying installation...
[2021-02-03 17:00:51] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-02-03 17:00:55] Verification complete
[2021-02-03 17:03:43] Background update loop checking for update. . .
[2021-02-03 17:04:02] Checking for available updates...
[2021-02-03 17:04:36] Downloading manifest: http://client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
```

The terminal then start something called "`STEAM_HEAVY_RUNTIME`", freezes, and ultimately either the process or the computer stop.

I hope you can be in some help !

Comment: My computer is a potato computer Is this a brand?

Comment: It is a Dell computer from 2015 (model : Latitude 3570)  that often freeze and crash when I open heavy software. That could impact my problem, because every time I try to launch Steam my computer freeze at least 2-3 second.

Comment: Maybe do not use Ubuntu use one of the light weight version like Kubuntu more suited to lower power machines. Steam still may not run not sure why you would try to install on a known non working machine.

Comment: I will probably have to swich to Kubuntu but i do not have the time to do it so currently and for at least 1 month.  ||    Moreover, I tried reinstalling steam because it worked flawlessly for a long time before. I then though that some updates would have broken it (by deleting a needed dependency by example?), and often a new installation corrects the problem (in windows at least). I guess it's not the case in linux. :/